# How do I fix a Corrupted NFSS tables

Tags: fonts, errors

I'm getting this error.  From poking around I think it might be due to a missing language file, but I don't know how to find out which.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TS1/aett/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TS1/cmr/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textquotesingle' on input line 55.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd")
! Corrupted NFSS tables.
wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables}
                                                  error@fontshape else let f...
l.56 ...oxbacktick=\hbox{\begin{normalsize}\verb.`
                                                  .\end{normalsize}}%
```

Comment: You seem to be using the **ae** package. Don't: it's obsolete. Install the CM-Super fonts or say `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: Try and show a minimal example reproducing the error.

Answer (score 2):

A corrupt NFSS table means that some package has incorrectly set up fonts: the standard LaTeX set up has all of the tables working. Properly fixing this type of issue is a job for whoever creates the font package. However, for you as a user it's a question of isolating the problematic package, using the usual approach of trying one package at a time until the culprit is identified. You can then report the issue, if the package is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and can confirm that `\usepackage{lmodern}` solved it.

In my case I tracked the unexpected behavior to the way `Sweave` changes the behavior of `siunitx` inside math delimiters, like so:

This is a file called `temp.Rnw` which has `Sweave.sty` (available [here](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/share/texmf/tex/latex/Sweave.sty)) in the same directory.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%
%\usepackage{Sweave}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx} % SI units
%
\begin{document}
%
'siunitx' makes writing \SI{1}{\ul} easy!

But if you're in math mode it's harder: $\SI{1}{\ul}$
%
\end{document}
```

I run `LaTeX` on this and get something like: [image]

Now if I uncomment the `\usepackage{Sweave}` and `LaTeX` again I exit abnormally with

```
wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables}
                                                  error@fontshape else let f... 
l.11 ...'re in math mode it's harder: $\SI{1}{\ul}
                                                  $

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TS1/aer/m/n' undefined 
(Font)          using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead 
(Font)          for symbol `c__siunitx_mu_tl' on input line 11.
```

Now uncommenting the `\usepackage{lmodern}` and everything works as before.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and `\usepackage{lmodern}` didn't help me, but the solution was pretty straightforward.

My file appeared to have literally the symbol `ε` instead of `$\epsilon$`, and it seems this sort of symbols break the compilation. Just check there are no "weird" characters in your document and it should work.